# how to add user to openfire by angularjs $http using OF RestApi?

Tags: angularjs, rest, cors, openfire

I am using OpenFire Rest APi v 1.2.3 to add new members to it. this is my code to send my request.

```
 var par ={
                username:$scope.currentItem.tel1,
                password:buildKey($scope.currentItem.password),
                name:$scope.currentItem.name,
                email: $scope.currentItem.email
            };
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: baseCfg.xmpp_server + "users",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization":"Basic YWRtaW46IVFBWjFxYXo="
                },
                data:JSON.stringify(par)
            }).then(function () {
                console.log("done");
            }, function () {
                console.log("error");
            });
```

but I am getting this response :

> OPTIONS 403 forbidden

and in request headers there is no headers and parameters.

Comment: I've never used the api you mentioned, but the problem seems quite common and is not connected with your client code. Generally, when you use a POST request, browsers firstly send a preflight request (with method type = OPTIONS). It seems that your Rest API doesn't allow OPTIONS method and it should be enabled on the server to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

it was my silly mistake witch i donot turn off my restapi.
i must go to this path an enable it:

OpenFire admin panel > server > server settings > and check **Enable**